# Function template parameters failing to convert type during compilation

Tags: type-conversion, c++17, implicit-conversion, template-specialization, function-templates

While trying to use a function template that calls a class's specialized static function template it is failing to convert its parameter from the template parameter list.

Here is the function that I'm calling in main:

```
template<class Engine, typename Type, template<typename = Type> class Distribution, class... DistParams>
Type randomGenerator( RE::SeedType seedType, std::size_t seedValue, std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list, DistParams... params ) {
    static Type retVal = 0;
    static Engine engine = RE::getEngine<Engine>( seedType, seedValue, list );
    static Distribution<Type> dist = RD::getDistribution<Type, Distribution>( params... );
    retVal = dist( engine );
    return retVal;
}
```

---

A little bit about the function above:

The `Type` represents the return value of the distribution such as `int`, `unsigned`, `char`, etc for `Integral Types` that work with distributions such as `uniform_int_distribution<IntType>` or `Real Types` such as `float`, `double` for distributions like `uniform_real_distribution<RealType>`.

The terms `RE` & `RD` are typedefs of two classes.

```
typedef RandomEngine RE;
typedef RandomDistribution RD;
```

Both classes follow the same pattern as they have delete constructors and all of their methods are declared a static.

The 2nd line in the function is using the template parameter `<class Engine>` to represent what kind of engine from the `<random>` header file we want to use from the static methods in `class RandomEngine{...}`. Each of the engine types has it's own function to create an engine, seed it by the seeding type and seed values and then returns a reference of the engine. All of the functions in the `RandomEngine class` are non template functions. So I then went ahead and made generalized function template `RE::getEngine<Engine>( parameters );` in this `RandomEngine class` that you can see in this function template `randomGenerator()`. Then I specialized this function for each engine type. I had no problems with doing that.

This brings me to the next line with the `RandomDistribution class` I'm trying to follow a similar pattern as I did with the `RandomEngine` I made a generalized function template `RD::getDistribution<Type, Distribution>( params... );`

---

Before I get to the `RD::getDistribution<...>(...)` function both of the classes above are non templates. The first class `RandomEngine` has zero function templates for its engines except the generalized `getEngine()` The difference with this class as opposed to the `RandomDistribution` is that every function in this class is a function template, because the `<random>` library's distribution functions require it. So now I have to not only template this generalized function as I did for `getEngine()` I have to also use a variadic parameter pack as different distributions takes a different amount of arguments.

---

Here is my declaration of my generalized function in the `RandomDistribution` class that is found in the header file:

```
template<typename Type, template<typename = Type> class Distribution, class... DistParams>
static Distribution<Type>& getDistribution( DistParams... params ) {
    return getUniformIntDistribution( params... );
}
```

Then I have this attempt of a specialization for this function in the cpp file for just one of the other distributions:

```
template<>
static std::uniform_real_distribution<>& RandomDistribution::getDistribution() {
    return RandomDistribution::getUniformRealDistribution();
}
```

I would like to do this for all the other distributions that I'm supporting.

---

I am using the stand alone function template `randomGenerator()` in my main function like this:

```
{
    std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list{};
    unsigned val = randomGenerator<std::mt19937, unsigned, std::uniform_int_distribution>
    ( RE::USE_CHRONO_CLOCK, std::size_t( 12 ), list, 1, 100 );
    std::cout << val << std::endl;

}
```

When I compile `RandomGenerator.cpp` file it compiles without error;
however, when I compile `main.cpp` I am getting a compiler error stating that it can not convert from `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>&` to `std::uniform_int_distribution<Type>&`

and it is pointing to my class's generalized function template that is declared in `RandomGenerator.h`file.

For some reason; `Type` is not being assigned or casted to the type that is passed into `randomGenerator's` template parameter list.

I'm stuck at this point. I know what the compiler message is saying; I don't what to do to fix. What can be done to resolve this conversion failure?

Answer (score 0):

Okay scrap that whole idea above: I went and entirely rewritten my classes into a single class. The class itself is now a class template. And it looks like this:

```
#ifndef GENERATOR_H
#define GENERATOR_H

#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

enum SeedType { USE_CHRONO_CLOCK, USE_RANDOM_DEVICE, USE_SEED_VALUE, USE_SEED_SEQ };

template<class Engine, class Type, template<typename> class Distribution>
class Generator {
public:
    using Clock = std::conditional_t<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
        std::chrono::steady_clock>;

private:
    Engine _engine;
    Distribution<Type> _distribution;
    Type _value;

public:

    template<class... Params>
    explicit Generator( Engine engine, Params... params ) : _engine( engine ) {
        _distribution = Distribution<Type>( params... );
    }

    void seed( SeedType type = USE_RANDOM_DEVICE, std::size_t seedValue = 0, std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list = {} ) {
        switch( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK:  { _engine.seed( getTimeNow() );  break; }
            case USE_RANDOM_DEVICE: { std::random_device device{};
                                      _engine.seed( device() );      break; }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE:    { _engine.seed( seedValue );     break; }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ:      { std::seed_seq seq( list );
                                      _engine.seed( seq );           break; }
        }
    }

    void generate() {
        _value = _distribution( _engine );
    }

    Type getGeneratedValue() const {
        return _value;
    }

    Distribution<Type> getDistribution() const {
        return _distribution;
    }

    std::size_t getTimeNow() {
        std::size_t now = static_cast<std::size_t>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
        return now;
    }

};

#endif // !GENERATOR_H
```

And to use it is as simple as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include "generator.h"

int main() {

    // Engine, Seeding Type, & Distribution Combo 1
    std::mt19937 engine1;
    Generator<std::mt19937, short, std::uniform_int_distribution> g1( engine1, 1, 100 );
    g1.seed( USE_RANDOM_DEVICE );
    std::vector<short> vals1;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        g1.generate();
        auto v = g1.getGeneratedValue();
        vals1.push_back( v );
    }

    int i = 0;
    for( auto& v : vals1 ) {

        if( (i % 10) != 0 ) {
            std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        }       
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Engine, Seeding Type, & Distribution Combo 2
    std::ranlux48 engine2;
    std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list2{ 3, 7, 13, 17, 27, 31, 43 };

    Generator<std::ranlux48, unsigned, std::binomial_distribution> g2( engine2, 50, 0.75 );
    g2.seed( USE_SEED_SEQ, std::size_t(7), list2 );

    std::vector<unsigned> vals2;

    for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        g2.generate();
        auto v = g2.getGeneratedValue();
        vals2.push_back( v );
    }

    for( auto& v : vals2 ) {

        if( (i % 10) != 0 ) {
            std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw( 3 ) << v << " ";
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Engine, Seeding Type, & Distribution Combo 3
    std::minstd_rand engine3;
    Generator<std::minstd_rand, float, std::gamma_distribution> g3( engine3, 0.22222f, 0.7959753f );
    g3.seed( USE_CHRONO_CLOCK );

    std::vector<float> vals3;

    for( int i = 0; i < 200; i++ ) {
        g3.generate();
        auto v = g3.getGeneratedValue();
        vals3.push_back( v );
    }

    for( auto& v : vals3 ) {

        if( (i % 5 ) != 0 ) {
            std::cout << std::setw( 12 ) << v << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw( 12 ) << v << " ";
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";


    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```